# Difference between content protection systems in MPEG-DASH manifest

Tags: drm, mpeg-dash

Sorry if my question seems inappropriate but I am a beginner with MPEG-DASH and DRM technology and something is not clear to me. I am looking at the following dash test examples: http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/v1.5.1/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html

In particular i am focused on the "Cablelabs cenc" examples with licenses. can someone explain me the difference between:

- CableLabs Cenc ClearKey
- CableLabs Cenc Widevine
- CableLabs Cenc Playready

By looking at the manifests, there is no difference between them. Only the "cenc:default_KID" parameter changes. So, how can the videoplayer understand if and which specific license is needed?

Moreover, to acquire the license sometimes a initialisation data is needed. What exactly this data contains?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MPEG-DASH you can choose to have the DRM-specific initialization information in one of two places:

- Directly in the MPD (what you call the "manifest" in your question), or
- You can have it in the "init segment", which is essentially an ISO Base Media File Format fragment containing (typically) the 'moov' atom and -- relevantly for this question -- the 'pssh' atom. The 'pssh' atom is important because it contains the DRM-specific header, such as the PlayReady one or the WideVine one.

In this specific case, it's the second option, i.e. **you have your DRM information in the initialization segment**. Specifically:

## PlayReady

if you look at the [PlayReady MPD](http://html5.cablelabs.com:8100/cenc/pr/dash.mpd), you'll see it contains an element like this:

```
<Representation id="3" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640020" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="25" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="2276507">
   <BaseURL>video_1280x720_h264-2500k_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
   <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="1789-2024">
      <Initialization range="0-1788"/>
   </SegmentBase>
</Representation>
```

If you look at the [init segment referenced by the `<BaseURL>`](http://html5.cablelabs.com:8100/cenc/pr/video_1280x720_h264-2500k_dashinit.mp4) element in a hex editor, you'll see that it has an ISO BMFF "box" called 'pssh', followed by something clearly recognizable as Unicode text which reads something like `<WRMHEADER ... />`, which is Microsoft PlayReady's rights management header. If you dig further, you'll recognize in there a "license acquisition URL", which is how a DRM client (such as for example Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 or higher) can obtain the license.

## WideVine

Now you can do the same using the [WideVine MPD](http://html5.cablelabs.com:8100/cenc/wv/dash.mpd), which references [its own init segment from its own `<BaseURL>` element](http://html5.cablelabs.com:8100/cenc/wv/video_1280x720_h264-2500Kb_dashinit.mp4). If you look at *that* in a hex editor, you'll find a 'pssh' box there, too, which in turn contains a WideVine-specific rights management header. By means of that a WideVine DRM client (such as for example Chrome) can obtain a WideVine license.

Comment: If you ever need to inspect the PSSH header when it's baked into the video, see: https://github.com/use-sparingly/pywvpssh